# Why wouldn't undo work after delete?

Tags: editing, undo

I'm in 10.4, and it seems like after I paste undo works fine, but after I delete it does nothing.

Any reason for this?

Comment: I don't see a problem in Mathematica 11.3.  If you are fairly new to Mathematica, you may not be aware of how many years Mathematica was without any useful undo capability.  I think (perhaps unsurprisingly) that it took them a few iterations to get it working as well as it does now.

Comment: @mikado Yea I'm moving to Maple in a few months I think :/

Comment: @mikado and, no, I've been at it for ~1.5 years and I'm still tripping over nonsense like this. Between this stuff and Wolfram's sparkling and generous personality methinks I'm better off on Maple.

Comment: @jamesson I think it would be helpful if you provided an example.  Generally speaking, you can undo a deletion in 10.4.

Comment: I also am experiencing no ability to undo after selecting a large block of code and accidentally pressing the delete key.  It doesn't seem to be repeatable, though.  Mathematical 11.3.0.0 on MacOS.